# ajax jquery post, needs some fine tuning for a beginner

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

i'm new to javascript and jquery and as part of a college project i need to make periodic checks the database to see if there has been changes. if there has been changes, i want the result of that change to 'alert' to the screen just to prove the AJAX call is working. i'm using asp.net and c#.

my scenario is: user 'A' logs in and sees user 'B' in a listbox populated by a global list. 'A' clicks on 'B' and clicks the play button. as this happens 'B's' invitedBy column in the User table in the DB changes to 'A'. this is where my problem is, i want to have a script that  periodically accesses a web method in my UserDAO.cs class - which has a method that queries the invitedBy column in the DB (this has been tested and works). i'm having trouble getting this working, would someone take a look and see if they can spot anything. all help would be much appreciated!

DBPolling.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
function ajaxRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UserDAO.cs/queryInvitedBy",// is this correct way to input url?
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resultData) {
            //console.log(result);// i found this in an example...needed?
            if (resultData.status == 'pending') {
                setTimeout(function () { ajaxRequest(); }, 5000); // wait 5 seconds than call ajax request again
            } else {
                var result = eval(resultData);
                alert("You have been invited" + result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});

UserDAO.cs

```
[WebMethod]
    public string queryInvitedBy()
    {
        // New user
        User user;

        // Open the NHibernate session
        ISession session = NHibernateHttpModule.CurrentSession;

        IQuery q = session.CreateQuery(
            "FROM User WHERE InvitedBy IS NOT NULL");
            // Assign values to the ? placehoders, by their index (0,1, etc.)

        // Make sure List is not empty
        if (q.List<User>().Count > 0)
            // set user to first item in List
            user = q.List<User>()[0];
        else
            // set user to null if none found
            user = null;

        // If no users found, returned user will be blank, otherwise the valid user
        string result = user.InvitedBy.ToString();
        return result;
    }
```

i've been following online tutorials and looking at Qs similar to mine to get this far, so please let me know if i'm on the right track, or offer a solution if you see any problems.

Comment: +1 for detailed question and well-coommented code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your .aspx page, not the code behind.

`url: "UserDAO.aspx/queryInvitedBy",`

Comment: thanks for the reply. i don't have a UserDAO.aspx page. UserDAO.cs is an App_Code class where i can peform basic data operations like insert, update etc. does the method need to be in the .cs file or should i move it elsewhere, its own .aspx page maybe?

Comment: TCC is right though, even if UserDAO is not a page, you can't call a .cs file.  Those are compiled at runtime and can't be called from javascript, you need to have a url to call that will direct your request to the method you're after

Comment: okay i understand that i can't call the .cs file, what would be the best way to implement what you guys are suggesting? i'm just finding it a bit confusing as i need to reference things like System.Web.Services, Nhibernate etc.

Comment: Create a new UserDAO.aspx page with a UserDAO.cs or whatever name you choose. Copy your [WebService] method to your new UserDAO.cs code behind. You can also reference System.Web.Services.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, your problem is calling the function over and over again.

you could define a global timer variable in your javascript

```
var timer;
```

and create a function

```
function check(){
clearTimeout(timer);
//do the ajax thing here

timer=setTimeout('check()',5000);
}
```

now, when you want to call the funcion use

```
timer=setTimeout('check()',5000);
```

and it should work every 5 secods....

is that what you needed?

Comment: thanks for the reply. what do you mean 'calling the function over and over again'? that is what i want to do. i want this script to use (by short polling) the web method in UserDAO every 5 seconds to see if a logged in user's invitedBy column has been altered, and then if it has, alert to the screen: ("you have been invited by " + result). i havn't got it working yet, and as i said i'm new to jquery, javascript and making ajax calls - so i was hoping someone could look through and point out anything i was doing wrong.